# install mysql server on windows using batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I'm installing mysql on windows using batch script.

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "D:\MySQL\mysql-installer-community-5.6.34.0.msi" /qn /norestart

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"%Program Files%MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo MySQL has been installed successfully

setx PATH "%%Program Files%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin%;"
pause

cd /

c:

mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1';"
;

mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

In the above script any mistake is there.I am getting the error.
"The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: `%%Program Files%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin%;` Why so many `%`? But I think the problem might be in the space. If you are looking for he environment variable, that contains the path to the directory `Drive:\Program Files`, you would have to use `%ProgramFiles` rather than `%Program Files%`. This has to be corrected twice in your script; once after `echo Configurating [...]` and once after `setx PATH [...]`.

Comment: I did %ProgramFiles%,But getting the same issue "The system Cannot find the path specified".

Comment: Place an echo in front of the commands and see what you will get. This makes it easier to find the mistakes. Also: On which point does it fail? You have a few `echo`es in your script. After which one do you get the message?

Comment: C:\batch>data.bat
Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...
Configurating MySQL Server...
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldb" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8
Press any key to continue . . .
MySQL has been installed successfully
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ECHO is off.
please look on this error

Comment: Try `set PATH=%PATH%;<path to mysql here>` as a substitute for setx.

Comment: @echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...
msiexec /i "mysql-5.6.34-win64.msi" /qn
echo Configurating MySQL Server...
"%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldb" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8
pause
set PATH=%PATH%;\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin%;"
mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myuser';"
mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myuser' WITH GRANT OPTION;" I'm using this script

Comment: Your line where you set the path is still wrong! This should work: `set PATH=%PATH%;%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin`

Comment: I modified again same issue is coming. My request is please check once again script. Is it right or anything to modify on the script. Script is there in above comment's

Comment: 1) If you use the script that is in the comments above there is an issue! have a look at this line: `set PATH=%PATH%;\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin%;"` 1a) You are missing `%ProgramFiles%` in front of the rest of the path. 1b) The `%"` in the end is causing the problem! Delete it! 2)Do not post code in the comments without formatting but [edit] it in your question. Note that you can mark code and click the symbol `{}` to format it as code!

Comment: I modified as per your suggestion but same issue is coming..............

Comment: So the installation runs fine and after that he cannot find the path? Have you looked up where it gets installed?

Comment: It's not installing

Comment: Then I think your first question should be how to fix the `msiexec` command and not how to find a path that is nonexistent.

Comment: Okay okay............ can you please let me know how can i fix msiexec issue...

Comment: No. I have literally no idea. But you might want to google for msiexec and look for a technet website.

Comment: Use the logging options of [msiexec](http://ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html) to know what happened wrong: add `/lx <logfile_x> /lv <logfile_v> /l* <logfile>` (replace `<logfile...>` with the location you want). It might (actually it will) reveal you what happened wrong

Answer (score 0):

This following script seems to work for me. I just removed the spaces between %Program Files% and added a backward slash after %ProgramFiles%.

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i mysql-5.5.25a-winx64.msi /passive

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q 
ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=MYISAM 
Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo MySQL has been installed successfully

setx PATH "%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin%;"
pause
```

P.S. Batch script and installer are present in the same folder.